# fetching of greengrass v2 job (component update) when certain conditions are satisfied

Tags: aws-iot, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-greengrass

I have a use case where the update of an AWS GreenGrass v2 component can not be done unless the device is in a certain state.

This state is external to the GreenGrass runtime, but is obviously accessible.

My question is:

How can fetching a job, to be executed on a device, be delayed? or;
How can a job be fetched when a certain condition is satisfied?

We have a fleet of devices that will be in various states.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at this as well.  I don't have a specific answer yet, but I think the intention is that you configure your deployment to notify the application before running the deployment on each thing.  The application then listens for the notifications and responds back whether to defer the deployment or proceed.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/ipc-component-lifecycle.html#ipc-operation-subscribetocomponentupdates